# Showing a function is Riemann Integrable

Tags: real-analysis

The problem states: Let $x_{0}\in[a,b]$, $f(x_{0})=1$ and $f(x)=0$, $\forall x\in [a,b]$ s.t. $x\neq x_{0}$. Show that $f$ is Riemann integrable and that $\int fdx=0$.

My first thoughts were to approach this by looking at different partitions and the upper and lower sums. It was pretty straightforward with the lower sum and easy to show the lower Riemann integral was equal to 0. But I am having trouble with the upper sum and integral.

I started with considering the possible partitions. First let $P$ be a partition such that $a=p_{0}\leq p_{2}\leq\cdots\leq p_{n-1}\leq p_{n}=b$. Then I imagined two cases: first where $p_{k-1}< x_{0}< p_{k}$ for some $1\leq k\leq n$ or $a=x_{0}$ or $b=x_{0}$. This results in $U(P,f)=\Delta p_{k}$. And secondly where $x_{0}=p_{k}$ which yields $U(P,f)=p_{k+1}-p_{k-1}$.

I was hoping I could find a partition s.t. $\inf U(P,f)=0$ but have had no luck. I'm hoping someone could point me in the right direction or correct any errors I have made that are hindering me.

Comment: Take a partition of the form $\pi=(a,x_0-\epsilon, x_0+\epsilon, b)$. Compute $U(f,\pi)$.

Comment: Ok this is very helpful, but I can't seem to finish the problem. I use a similar partition and then compute the upper sum. Then using $U(P,f)-L(P,f)<\epsilon$ I can show $f$ is Riemann integrable. But how do I show $\int fdx=0$?

Comment: Note that $f=0$ almost everywhere, and $f$ is continuous for all but a finite number of points, so by Lebesgue criteria for Riemann  integrability $f$ is integrable and it's integral equals zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $x_0 \in (a,b)$ and $\epsilon < \min (x_0-a,b-x_0) $.
Let $\pi_\epsilon = (a,x_0-\epsilon, x_0+\epsilon, b)$, then
$L(\pi_\epsilon, f) = 0$, $U(\pi_\epsilon,f) = 2 \epsilon$.
Hence $\sup_P L(P,f) = \inf_P U(P,f) = 0$.

(Note that we always have $L(P,f) \le U(P,f)$.)

The cases $x_0 =a$ or $x_0 = b$ are treated similarly.